# Url change but still on the same page django

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

When i change to the page "lostitems" it successfull show up, but when i change to another page "addlostitem" it's still on the same page as before, but the url change the way that i want

**Urls.py**

```
url(r'lostitems/$', views.LostItemsView.as_view(), name='lost_items'),
url(r'lostitems/addlostitems/$', views.RegisterLostView.as_view(), name='register_lost'),
```

**Views.py**

```
class LostItemsView(generic.ListView):
    model = Wallet
    template_name = 'lostfound/lost_items.html'

class RegisterLostView(View):
    model = Wallet
    template_name = 'lostfound/register_lost.html'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your URL patterns matches (partially) with the first in order, this should fix that:

```
url(r'^lostitems/$', views.LostItemsView.as_view(), name='lost_items'),
url(r'^lostitems/addlostitems/$', views.RegisterLostView.as_view(), name='register_lost'),
```

Notice I have added the `^` hat sign in beginning to force full match.

Comment: thanks, when i add the ^ after that, it change to the another page, but the page is white right now,

Comment: Well then check your `register_lost.html` and see if it extends properly from `base.html` (if any) and has content. In browser check the html source of the page.

Comment: i already check it, it should be run properly
this is my register_lost.html : 

{% extends 'lostfound/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Register Lost Items{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% load staticfiles %}

     <h1>Hello</h1>

{% endblock %}

Comment: Please http://dpaste.com/ your `lostfound/base.html` as well as `lostfound/register_lost.html` (yes again) and share the link.

Comment: Just noticed why your `RegisterLostView` is extending from simple `View` isn't it needs to be inherit from `FormView` or `ListView` or `TemplateView` or something?

Comment: ah thankyou so much :) that's my fault cause i try for a simple View before, so i forget to correct my code

actually, it was worked when you said that i miss the ^ so i should add it